# How to pass an event of a button click to a callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cmw0s2rk/

```
function HandleTopNavClick($elem, pretext = "", replace = false, e) {
  debugger;
  e.preventDefault();
  var href = $elem.href;
}

$("ul.check-it li a").on("click", HandleTopNavClick($(this), "clickhere_", true, event));
```

Any idea why the `event` is not carrying over to the function?

Comment: You're only meant to add a reference to `HandleTopNavClick` as the callback, not the result of calling it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are synchronously calling handleTopNavClick, then passing its result into .on. Instead, you want to create a function and pass that into .on, which will later be called back with the event.

```
$("ul.check-it li a").on("click", function(event) {
  HandleTopNavClick($(this), "clickhere_", true, event)
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably meant to use `HandleTopNavClick` as the callback function, but instead, you are using the return value of the function as the callback function, which is undefined.

You can just use `HandleTopNavClick` as the callback function for the click event handler and use `this` to refer to the element.

```
function HandleTopNavClick(e) {
  debugger;
  e.preventDefault();
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
}

$("ul.check-it li a").on("click", HandleTopNavClick);
```

JSFiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cmw0s2rk/8/

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Nicholas, this can be achieved with arrow functions, which can sometimes read a bit nicer.

```
$("ul.check-it li a").on("click", event => HandleTopNavClick($(this), "clickhere_", true, event));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, changing it to an arrow function will also change what `$(this)` results in and thus break the code. jquery invokes the callback with `this` equal to the dom node on which the event listener was created, but that will only work with a normal function.